# How do i make my int update more frequently?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am making this evolution game with chickens, where the chickens are laying eggs and then an int is keeping the number of eggs the chickens have laid. That int is named "EggNumber". I also have an array that counts all the chickens in the game. Then I take my eggnumber and add the chickencount-array's number to that and then I get how many eggs the chickens have made. But I have seen a little bug in my script. That is because when I add a new chicken to the game, my EggNumber goes back to the number it was before it last updated. How do I fix this?. I don't know how to fix the problem because I am a noob at programming. The code is down below:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
    
public class EggLayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Egg;
    
    public GameObject Chicken;
    
    public Text EggText;
    
    public int EggNumber = 0;
    
    public float NewEggTime = 2f;
    
    public int ChickenCount = 0;
    
    public int OldEggNumber;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Egg.SetActive(false);
        StartCoroutine("MakeEggVisible");
    
        GameObject[] ChickenToFind = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Chicken");
        int ChickenCount = ChickenToFind.Length;
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        EggText.text = EggNumber.ToString("0");
    }
    
    IEnumerator MakeEggVisible()
    {
        GameObject[] ChickenToFind = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Chicken");
        ChickenCount = ChickenToFind.Length;
    
        while (true)
        {
            EggNumber = OldEggNumber;
    
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(NewEggTime);
            GameObject[] ChickenToFind1 = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Chicken");
            ChickenCount = ChickenToFind1.Length;
    
            OldEggNumber = EggNumber + 1 * ChickenCount;
            EggNumber = OldEggNumber;
            Egg.SetActive(true);
    
            EggNumber = OldEggNumber;
    
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(NewEggTime);
    
            Egg.SetActive(false);
            EggNumber = OldEggNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in general in `Start` you do ` int ChickenCount = ChickenToFind.Length;` which is a new local variable only existing within `Start` .. you don't actually set your field `ChickenCount` here

Comment: I recomended you the use of some nomenclature to avoid this kind of errors. You can use always "this" in your fields/properties/methods like "this.ChickedCount = ..." or use an underscore for your private fields "_chickenCount = ...".

Comment: Your solution seems quite complicating for such a simple task. Could you tell us more how exactly do you want it to behave? I'd make a script for Chicken which will contain integer of how many eggs that chicken have made and all you need to do is find all chickens and combine number of eggs that they have made.